# How can i get constants for column types in Postgres

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

For MySQL, I can find the column type constants from [this](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE-module.html) Python lib

What about Postgres? I sought for them [here](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2) them on  but can't find them
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of constants mentioned in the [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/).

- [Isolation level constants](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#isolation-level-constants)
- [Transaction status constants](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#transaction-status-constants)
- [Connection status constants](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#connection-status-constants)
- [Poll constants](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#poll-constants)
- [Additional database types](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#additional-database-types)

Out of those additional database types are the one you are looking for.